# mbed.h library for stm32 F207zg

Tags: build, microcontroller, stm32, firmware, nucleo

I tried to use mbed.h library from this link: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/#679d24833acf0a0b5b0d528576bb37c70863bc4e for nucleo F207ZG but it fails during build because of device.h library. I am new in the field so I am not sure how to solve this. I tried to change main.c file to main.cpp and the problem I had with cstddef.h library solved and device.h error appeared. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeSGj.png)

Comment: You will need to at least share the error message you are seeing.